# Simplest way to convert subscript numbers

Tags: php, character-encoding

we get book titles from different sources (library systems) (with possibly different encoding, but mostly utf8). These strings are shown in the web and via export to Endnote and RefWorks. RefWorks (windows Quotation system) does not  accept any other encoding than ANSI.

In the RIS/Refworks export, activating the line

```
$smarty = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $smarty);
```

Example string

```
Diphosphen-komplexes (CO) 5CrPhPPPhCr(CO) 5
```

does suddenly cut off everything after the first subscript char (the rectangles). These chars are also not correctly printed in HTML but this output is okay because nothing is cut off. In UTF-8 export file encoding nothing is cut off, too. Despite that, the Windows software can't read UTF-8.

The simplest solution would be to convert any subscript number to a regular number. Everything would work quite well then. But I could not find any simple solution to this. Working with hex codes is the only thing I could imagine. This solutions is also preferred for use in our Solr index.

Anybody knows a better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example string contains [Private Use code points](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) such as U+E5F8. By definition, no standard assigns any meaning to them; their use is purely by private agreements. It is thus impossible to convert them to anything, or to do anything with them, without knowing or inferring the private agreements involved. Some systems use Private Use code points to represent some symbols that are assigned to those points in some special font. Knowing what that font is and inspecting it may thus help to find out the agreement.

The conversion would need to be coded separately, in an ad hoc manner, since there is an an hoc agreement involved.

“ANSI”, which here means windows-1252, does not contain any subscript characters. In the context of a chemical formula, replacing subscript digits by normal digits does not change the meaning, and the formula is understandable, though it looks unprofessional.

When converting to HTML format (or other rich text format), you can use normal digits wrapped in elements that cause subscript rendering (or otherwise style them). HTML has the `sub` element for this, but its implementations differ between browsers and tend to be a poor quality, so a better approach is to generate `<span class=sub>...</span>` and use CSS to set the vertical position and font size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It saved me hours of coding! I'm going too remove all those undefined chars so the string looks clean in our export file. Having undefined chars in a string is bad for Solr indexing I guess. I don't think its possible to parse special HTML/CSS for these chars.

Comment: I’m afraid it would delete essential information to just remove the Private Use code points. Googling a bit I found the document http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022328X85871412 where  those code points appear *in addition to* subscript digits (implemented using `sub`). So I suppose those code points are supposed to be rendered as some special characters, perhaps chemical bond symbols.

Comment: Comparing with another document http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=9022801 I came into conclusion that U+E5F8 is meant to stand for a simple bond symbol and U+E5F8 for a double bond symbol. There are no dedicated characters for them, but probably best characters are U+2013 EN DASH “–”, which is 0x96 in windows-1252, and U+003D EQUALS SIGN “=”, which is 0x3D in windows-1252. If some formulas have triple (or higher) bonds, things get difficult, since U+2261 IDENTICAL TO “≡” is not included in windows-1252 and has no apparent alternate notation.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your research. I'll now try to replace these chars to  dash or equality sign.